# IE Problem: Won't execute javascript loaded as part of AJAX content

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, dynamic

I'm loading AJAX content that contains a javascript function inside the AJAX content. I'm using the jQuery .load function and calling done() on completion.

```
$('#content').load(a, done);

function done()
{
    if(pagejs() == 'function')
    {
        pagejs();
    }
}
```

I'm not able to get the function to execute in IE 9 but in FF and Chrome the script is executed fine. In IE, I'm getting a **SCRIPT5007: Object expected** error on the `if(pagejs() == 'function')` line.

I added the compatibility meta tag:
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"  />` still with no success.

Here is a sample of the AJAX content:

```
<div id="about"><h1>About This Website</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">
function pagejs(){alert('content was loaded from dynamic script');}
</script>

<p>This is test AJAX content</p>
```

In IE, the `pagejs();` is undefined. Can someone please tell me how I can get IE to recognize this script? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `if(typeof(pagejs) == 'function')`

Answer (score 1):

```
pagejs() == 'function'
```

That executes pagejs and compares it's return value to the string `function`.

You want `typeof pagejs === 'function'`